# mysql の再起 CTE で float 型を取り扱いたい

Tags: mysql

MySQL の CTE の列の型に、double 精度の浮動小数点であることを強制したいのですが、これは可能でしょうか？

というのも、[MySQL :: MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual :: 13.2.13 WITH Syntax (Common Table Expressions)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-syntax) のページを見ていたのですが、

1. MySQL の CTE の syntax には column type を指定するところがない
2. "The types of the CTE result columns are inferred from the column types of the nonrecursive SELECT part only" つまり再起CTEでは最初の select 区のフィールドの型によって、その CTE 全体の戻り値の型が決定される。

   - つまり、初期値が int で、 union していく中で float/double になっていくような、集計系の CTE では、これはあまり良い性質ではないように思われる
3. 初期の select 区において double 型にキャストしようとドキュメントを見ているが、それを行う項目が見当たらない

   - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html を見ても、 Decimal (自分の理解だといわゆる BigDecimal) はあるが、 float/double に相当するデータ型はない

#### 質問

mysql の再起 CTE にて、戻り値フィールドの型を確実に double (倍精度浮動小数点) になるようにすることは可能ですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 8.0.17 から利用可能な、 cast as float/double で解決可能でした。

```
with recursive cte as(
  select cast(1 as double) as v
  union all
  select v * 1.1 from cte where v < 10
)
select v from cte;
```

これを確認するにあたって、一旦上記を view にした上で、 `desc` することで、たしかに double になっていることを確認しました。

```
mysql> create view testcastdouble as (
    ->   with recursive cte as(
    ->     select cast(1 as double) as v
    ->     union all
    ->     select v * 1.1 from cte where v < 10
    ->   )
    ->   select v from cte
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> desc testcastdouble;
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| v     | double | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

CTEには詳しくないので外してるかもしれませんが、

```
SELECT intvar + 0.0
```

みたいなことをすると結果は浮動小数点になると思います。

Comment: `create view foo as (select 1 + 0.0);` したのち、 `desc foo` をすると、依然 Decimal になっているっぽいな、と思っています。